# How to build full go program binary with gccgo?

Tags: gcc, go, gccgo

I have noticed that when using `go build` the binary result can be in excess of 2MB; but using `gccgo` the binary is less than 35k.

The other issue that I noticed when using `gccgo` is that the produced binary isn't runnable on another linux box (missing `libgo.so` I believe) but the `go build` binary runs just fine (so I imagine its because the binary includes all that is necessary to run?); is there a way to do this with `gccgo`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use the -static flag:

> Use the -static option to do a fully static link (the default for the gc compiler).

http://golang.org/doc/install/gccgo

Answer (score 5):

You can link libgo statically, while still linking the system libraries dynamically, by using the -static-libgo option.  (This applies to gccgo only).

Answer (score 0):

With go 1.8 or above, if go is built with `CGO_ENABLED=1` (default to 1), a native compilation links dynamically. Check this variable by running `go env CGO_ENABLED`.
You can switch to link statically by set the environment variable CGO_ENABLED to 0 when running go build.

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build
```

BTW, cross compiling uses static linkage automatically.